# How do I import excel xlsx or csv file into salesforce?

Tags: community, campaign-member

This it's my first time using Salesforce, I want to know how I can import the XLSX or converted into CSV file to Salesforce.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! If you're just getting started, Trailhead is the best source for introductions. There is a module on [importing data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_implementation_data_management/lex_implementation_data_import).

Comment: It's unclear whether or not your screenshot contains real personal data. If this data is real, **please remove it immediately**.

Comment: @David Reed This data isn't real, just for classwork. And this raw data was generate using mockaroo.com

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce provides ready to use tools to do so. In order to import data within Salesforce from an external CSV (comma separated value) file, you need to know the Salesforce object (equivalent of a table in a RDMS but much more than that..) and fields on the object (equivalent to columns of a table) to which you intend to push this data to.

I am assuming that the total number of records that you are attempting to import are less than 50,000 in number. These are the 3 most widely used tools that you could use here and do not imply an additional cost.

1. **Data Import Wizard** - You will be able to access this tool by logging into your Salesforce instance and navigating to ***Setup > Data Import Wizard***. This is limited to importing a maximum of 50,000 records only. Refer the following link to know the specifics of importing records into Salesforce using this method - [Import Data with the Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&type=5).
2. **Data Loader** - Data Loader is a client application used to import bulk data and perform DML operations on the Salesforce data. This tool will need to be installed locally on your machine before you can start using this. This utility comes in handy when you intend to insert or manipulate records greater than 50,000 in number. Refer the following link to know the specifics of installing and then importing records into Salesforce using this method - [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5)
3. **Workbench** - External utility available over the web and popularly used by Salesforce Admins and Developers however this is not owned or managed by Salesforce itself. Login to the utility using the credentials for the Salesforce instance to which the records need to be imported. Navigate to ***data > Insert*** within workbench and follow the relevant steps. Refer the following link to access Workbench - [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/insert.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en)..or [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5)